# Observer funtion is not working in app-component when trying to call it from service.ts angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observer-pattern

I have created a responsive side menu and that's work fine in-app component but when I am trying to move the function to my service.ts file it is not working at all. The below code is for my app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { MyDataServiceService } from './my-data-service.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'azad-app';
    name = '';
    
    constructor(private user: MyDataServiceService) { }
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.user.menuDisplay();
    }
}
```

And this is my function code in service.ts

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyDataServiceService {

    @ViewChild(MatSidenav)
    sidenav!: MatSidenav;

    constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver,) { }

    menuDisplay() {
        this.observer.observe(['(max-width:800px)']).subscribe((res) => {
            if (res.matches) {
                this.sidenav.mode = 'over';
                this.sidenav.close();
            } else {
                this.sidenav.mode = "side";
                this.sidenav.open();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post all your sidenav related code in your component and service please.

Comment: complete code added

Comment: You cannot use `@ViewChild()` in your service. Your service does not have template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a service, you should create a directive. Something like this:

```js
@Directive({selector: 'mat-sidenav[appMenu]'})
export class AppMenu implements OnDestroy{
  private readonly subscription = this.observer.observe(['(max-width:800px)']).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.matches) {
            this.sidenav.mode = 'over';
            this.sidenav.close();
        } else {
            this.sidenav.mode = "side";
            this.sidenav.open();
        }
    });
  constructor(private readonly sidenav: MatSidenav, private readonly observer: BreakpointObserver){ } 

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Angular can inject the componenet to the directive, with this method you can encapsulate your sidenav logic to a separate class.